# Visual Studio 2015 Stuck on Build started

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015

I have project made in visual studio 2015 with workflow for workflow manager 1.0, content type inherited from SharePoint 2013 workflow task, custom workflow task list, custom workflow history list and site column.

Site column is added to the content type and content type is added to the workflow task list. It have 3 feature, 1 feature with web scope is for content type, another one is  with site scope for site column and last one is with web scope for workflow, workflow history and task list.

I have event receiver for last feature where in I add content type to workflow task list on feature activate.

Now situation is that until some time it project was building very good but today suddenly it is taking time, stuck on building and nothing happens.

Yea I forget to mention that I am using cloud forge free version with Askh svn and tortoise svn.

Kindly can somebody help me what can be the issue.

**Update**

Well what I found that site column was in two features, so I removed it and put it in site scope feature. Than I put it for building, what I found that it building but taking 1 - 2 hour. What can be the reason !!!!!

Comment: Show the Output window log for Build

Comment: No error in the output window

Comment: Whats the build stuck on? What was added since it was building OK? Can you revert back to a version where it was building OK and compare?

Comment: Well what I found that site column was in two features, so I removed it and put it in site scope feature. Than I put it for building, what I found that it building but taking 1 - 2 hour. What can be the reason !!!!!